# Is the following special case of multiway number partitioning NP-hard?

Tags: np-hardness, time-complexity, partition-problem

The following problem is a decision problem of *multiway number partitioning* ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20multiway%20number,the%20Identical%2Dmachines%20scheduling%20problem.)) (Note that $k$ is also a part of an input in the following problem, while $k$ is a fixed number in wikipedia definition).

> Given $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n$ numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, decide if there exists a partition of the numbers into $k$ parts so that the sum of numbers in each part equals $\frac{\sum a_i}{k}$.

As this problem includes the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) as its special case (i.e. $k=2$), multiway number partitioning is NP-hard.

I would like to know whether the hardness still holds for the following special case of multiway number partitioning (The only difference is that we assume each number is $0$ or $1$).

> Given $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n$ numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \{0,1\}$, decide if there exists a partition of the numbers into $k$ parts so that the sum of numbers in each part equals $\frac{\sum a_i}{k}$.

In this special case, when $k$ or $n-k$ is a fixed constant, it is easy to see that the problem is polynomial-time solvable.
This is because if $k$ is a constant, you can use dynamic programming and if $n-k$ is a constant, the number of possible partitions is at most the polynomial of $n$, hence you can check the condition directly.

As there seems to be no efficient algorithm for middle size $k$, I conjecture that multiway number partitioning for this special case is still NP-hard.

I would like to know if anybody knows about this.

Comment: Since all input numbers are $0$ or $1$, such a partition exists if and only if $(\sum a_i)/k$ is an integer. This is trivial to check in polynomial time.

Comment: Nice first question! Welcome to our community!

Comment: To extend @Gamow's observation, the straightforward dynamic program for a problem with element universe $U = \{0,1,...,u\}$ has running time $O(nku^{k-1})$. When $u=1$, the only truly expensive part of the algorithm drops out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solultion. I should have come with that.